# Assign to function return value in while loop condition and catch exceptions along the way

Tags: python

I am learning C to assist my understanding of Python.

It is possible to write code like this in C:

```
int *ptr;
while ((c = scanf("%d", ptr)) == 1)
    // do something.
```

In Python, I would write

```
content = input()
while True:
    try:
       integer = int(content)
    except:
       print("try again")
       content = input()
    else:
       break
```

The Python code seems clumsy compared with C. Is it possible to write a more succinct version, similar to `((c = scanf("%d", ptr)) == 1)`?

Comment: The C may be succinct, but it is also wrong. It reads into an undefined memory location (uninitialized int*). And it's almost the opposite of the Python code (terminating on bad input rather than prompting until good input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Python 3.8 you can achieve something similar with [**Assignment Expressions**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) where you can write code such as

```
while (c := foo()) == bar:
    # do stuff with c
```

If you want to catch an exception along the way, you should define `foo` (or write a wrapper for `foo`) to handle that exception and return a value that fails (edit: or passes, depending on context) the check against `bar`.

In this specific case, the code could look like this:

```
def get_input():
    try:
        return int(input())
    except ValueError:
        return None # explicit is better than implicit

while (c := get_input()) is None:
    print('try again')

# do stuff with c
```

Comment: thank you, I find it's struggling to sharpen the python skills if not master C in advance.